# Rich text box in an Office 2007+ ribbon control

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, richtextbox, ribbon

I want to have a rich edit control on an Office 2007+ ribbon control from within an Office add-in. There is no rich text box in a VS2010 designer Toolbox.

Is there a way to put a custom control in a ribbon or is there any other less straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom task pane instead. Create a UserControl in your add-in project and put the rich text box on it with any other controls you want. Then add your user control to the custom task pane collection. Something like this:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var mytaskPane = new MyTaskPane();
    var myCustomTaskPaneCollection = Globals.Factory.CreateCustomTaskPaneCollection (null, null, "CustomTaskPanes", "CustomTaskPanes", this);
    var myCustomTaskPane = _myCustomTaskPaneCollection.Add(mytaskPane , "My Task Pane");
    myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
}
```